# Can't run r package mixOmics functions with large matrix

Tags: r, correlation, large-data

The mixOmics package is meant to analyze big data sets (e.g. from high throughput experiments), but it seems not be working with my big matrix.

I am having issues with both rcc (regularized canonical correlation) and tune.rcc (labmda parameters estimation for regularized can cor).

```
> str(Y)
 num [1:13, 1:17766] ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1:13] ...
 ..$ : chr [1:17766] ...

> str(X)
 num [1:13, 1:26] ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1:13] ...
 ..$ : chr [1:26] ...

tune.rcc(X, Y, grid1 = seq(0.001, 1, length = 5),
               grid2 = seq(0.001, 1, length = 5),
               validation = "loo", plt=F)
```

On Mavericks: runs forever (I quit R after hours)

Since I know Mavericks is problematic I've tried it on a Windows8 machine and on the mixOmics web interface.

On Windows 8:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.4 Gb
```

On web interface, since it is not possible to estimate lambdas (tune.rcc) I tried `rcc` with "some" lambdas and get:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.4 Gb
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?
Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: The obvious answer is that you've run out of memory. I don't know much about mixOmics, but just because it is designed to run on big data sets, doesn't mean it will run with a dataset as big as yours, or on a normal desktop. For example, their rcc demo data set has only 120 genes in it. Try on a bigger memory machine?

Comment: You are right it seems to be the only answer, unfortunately I do not have a bigger machine. It would be nice to know if anyone did run it on data as large as mine (which BTW is not excessive, being high throughput), but I couldn't find any example of this sort on the web.

Comment: Well it is just about possible that your particular input set is causing something to get stuck building larger and larger vectors, but I think that is unlikely. Have you tried it on a random subset of the genes? Or tried removing genes unexpressed genes or genes with low variance (I assume the first matrix is expression or some such?)

Comment: That is right, it's gene expression. I did try with only the first 1000 genes, and it worked - although it took a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Ali_Sce I faced a similar problem working with a gene expression dataset but you can resolve it by computing on your server or somehwere where you have bigger machine memory.